# Idiomatic way of selecting a component at runtime

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there an idiomatic way in Kotlin to choose the right composable at runtime? E.g. how do I avoid copy-pasting the "bunch of params" here:

```
if (isSystemInDarkTheme())
            Button(.... bunch of params)
else
            OutlinedButton(.... same bunch of params)
```

The IDE says "Function References of @Composable functions are not currently supported" when trying to use reflection.

Comment: You can extract the bunch of params into a data class and reuse

Comment: Not a bad idea but talking about https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#outlinedbutton, you'd still need to copy-paste 10 lines of code of setting params from that data class, plus overall you end up with more code than before.

Comment: Are these params needed outside of the function, you could assign them to a val at the start and just pass the value?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the max we can do (but still involves copy-pasting several lines of named arguments)